# Creating Cron Expression with of Days and Months Simultaneously

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, cronexpression, crontrigger

I simply want to create a cron expression that will execute a job after 'N' number of days. Where N can be any number greater than Zero.

So, It's alright if number is between 1 and 30. For Example Cron Expression to Execute Job after each 
25 days at 11 AM will be:

```
0 0 11 1/25 * ?  //'?' can only be specfied for Day-of-Month or Day-of-Week.
```

but if user exceeds this limit so it means we will have to execute job after 'M' months and 'D' days.

I am unable to understand how I can specify both day and month at the same time. Can anyone make me understand how I can create cron expression for this scenario. You may assume job to be execute after each '65' days

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that cron expressions don't support what you want to do. You'll need to pre-process the user's request and convert it into the appropriate cron expression, or implement your own timing routine, which could use cron behind the scene with some extra logic. Another suggestion is to put some restrictions on the user API that will only allow the user to enter cron friendly times like every month, every week, every 3 months, etc.